# Broken python3 packages Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, python

Is there any solution to fixing broken python3 packages with Ubuntu 20.04 rather than reinstalling Ubuntu?  If I have to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04, I'd just as soon try another Linux distro.

So far I've tried:

1. sudo apt update --fix-missing
2. sudo apt install -f
3. sudo dpkg --configure -a
4. sudo apt clean
5. sudo apt update

But no dependency problems are indicated.  The problem first reared its ugly head when I tried to implement a python virtual environment.

Comment: what errors do you see?

Comment: Oh, thanks for asking.  I see a lot of:  "The following packages have unmet dependencies:"  then a whole litany of them "Depends: python3-anyhio but it is not installable"  About six different python3 related modules.  Sigh!  I just don't feel like writing a book about it  As I said, it all started when I tried to create a virtual environment for Python.

Comment: VTC both the question and the answer seem too vague to help future users.

Comment: @MikeGreer without a "book" there is no way for us to know what is actually happening, and therefore we can't help you fix it. If you don't want to give all the details, you will just have to figure it out yourself. `virtualenv` is deprecated now afaik, so using it is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now it seems to work, but not with the command 'python3 -m venv project2_env'.  But, I can get it to work with the method described by another YouTube video using 'virtualenv project2_env'.  Both methods did not work earlier, but the latter one seems to work now.  I'm not sure if it's working according to Hoyle, because when I do a 'pip list' I get about 27 modules listed.  According to Corey Schafer's video, only one module at the most should be displayed with a newly created virtual environment.